# Capture network traffic simultaneously on three interfaces

Tags: networking, tcpdump, packet-capture

I need to capture traffic on a *CentOS 5* server which acts as a web proxy with 2 wan interfaces and 1 LAN. In order to troubleshoot a weird proxy problem, I would like to have a capture of a full conversation. Since external connections are balanced between the two WAN interfaces, I wonder if is it possible to capture **simultaneously** on all interfaces.

I have used `tcpdump` previously but it only admits one interface at a time. I can launch 3 parallel processes to capture on all interfaces but then I end up with 3 different capture files.

What is the right way of doing this ?

Comment: Added the info - Centos 5.

Comment: you could use mergecap to merge your 3 pcap files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use wireshark/tshark, there is a pseudo-interface named 'any' which takes all the interfaces.
`tshark -i any`
Wireshark is available on all plateforms

**Edit :** The any interface depends of libpcap : tcpdump have it ! `tcpdump -i any`

Comment: According to https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/480#issuecomment-138317953 the 'any' interface doesn't support promiscuous mode. (The answer was written for tcpdump but I guess it applies for tshark too.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where when I tried to dump broadcast traffic on *any* interface but tcpdump on the device replied *not a broadcast link* when I tried.

```
# tcpdump -i any broadcast -nn -v
tcpdump: not a broadcast link
```

I figured out I can just run multiple commands in parallel to get what I needed. It isn't the prettiest, but it worked for me.

```
tcpdump -i ath0 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath1 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath2 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath3 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath4 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath5 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath6 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath7 broadcast -n & tcpdump -i ath8 broadcast -n &
```

Then to kill all the parallel jobs and stop dumping:

```
kill `jobs -p`
```